# Magento2: Quick view button issue

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I have added quick view button on category product page.

Quick view button not showing on catalogsearch page.

I want to add Quick view button on catalogsearch page.

Please help me.

Comment: do you want a Quick button on category page right ?

Comment: No, Quick view button is showing on category page. But was not showing  on catlougesearch page. Issue is resolved. I have solved the script issue. Thanks! @DimplePanchal